# VBA PowerPoint - fill in textbox based on another textbox content on different slide

Tags: vba, dynamic, automation, textbox, powerpoint

I am a beginner with VBA, and I was wondering whether VBA could help me to automate presentation creation process.

My presentation template has on the top of each slide a textbox, which I would like to fill in with the text from a different slide.

**Example:**

*Slide 1 (Divider slide): includes only 1 textbox with text e.g. 1) Project scope*

*Slide 2, 3, 4 ... (Content slides): include title, charts, other text box, etc. - but also 1 "descriptive" textbox placed always in the same place on the top of each slide*

I would like this "descriptive" textbox to include text from Slide 1 (Divider slide).

Text in the "descriptive" textbox would change every time a new Divider slide would be detected, i.e. different "descriptive" textbox for each presentation part.

Not sure whether this can be done with VBA as I could not find anything similar online.
Thank you a lot for any information!

Comment: Consider repurposing the Footer placeholder for this. It's a simple way to have identical text appear on multiple slides. No programming required. Otherwise search on _powerpoint vba copy text box text to other slides_ to get multiple hits with sample code.